# XSS before a Re-Direct?

Tags: xss, redirect, owasp

So I found an old http page of a shopping website that doesn't have any filtering occurring. Using a proxy, I can inject whatever I want into the page, and it reflects in the application's response. If I load the same request in a browser, I get redirected to their HTTPS site. Is there any possibility of having XSS occur before the redirect happens? Or is the Javascript after the server side redirect, therefore is the reason why my payload isn't executing? I'm using a simple alert(1) which is reflected in the response on the http site, but not on the https page.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the sort or redirection, When the server redirects you, the Browser wont execute javascript code.

If its a Client side redirection with javascript your code should be executed.